# Rails best practice: another model or more model fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm working on an employee review section in my rails app.  So far, there are 7 categories that someone is reviewed on, which means that I want a rating and a comment for each category.

Is it better to have one Review model that has fields for each category rating and comment?  Or should I have two models - a Rating model and a Review model, where the Review model has_many ratings, and where a rating belongs_to a review?  I am trying to keep in mind that I may add, change, or delete review categories in the future.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be argued that this is a data modelling best practices question, not just a rails best practices question. It is difficult to give a 100% accurate answer without knowing more about your problem domain.

The most flexibility come from the multiple model approach. It will be easier to add (or remove) categories in the future. If, however, you are expecting a very large number of entries in these tables, you would get better performance out of the single model approach.

Comment: Using a category type table makes it easy to add a new category (simply add a new row to the type table), Assuming referential integrity were set up properly, removing a category is also easy: just delete that category type.

Comment: Thanks.  I completely missed the step of adding a categories model.  What would you consider a large number of entries?

Comment: @NicSlim The "large number of entries" threshold is ultimately dependent on the brand of database you are using, the number of concurrent users accessing the database, and the capabilities of the hardware that hosts the database. If you are measuring the number of entries in thousands, you are probably OK. In hundreds of thousands, probably not.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to keep it **DRY**. If you have multiple models doing the exact same thing (ratings + comments on categories), with the same controllers and views, then your code is **not DRY**.

You can easily make one model (and controller and view) that assigns a *type* to each category object. So say your categories are `["On Time", "Dresses neatly", "Keeps desk clean"]` Now you would have those each as a type for your model.

In fact, I'd make the Category table a three-way join

`Category belongs_to [Type, User, Supervisor]`

Category includes rating and comment.

So here's what Category object might look like:

```
id: 203
type_id: 2
rating: 4
comment: "Seems to get to work on time, 
          but usually late coming back from lunch"
user_id: 2
supervisor_id: 1
created_at: (whatever)
updated_at: (whatever)
```

You have your type object

```
id: 2
name: "On Time"
```

Your user objects

```
id: 1
name: Dick Jones
supervisor_id: null

id: 2
name: Clarence J. Boddicker
supervisor_id: 1
```

Comment: Yes.  It makes sense to have a separate type object.  Originally I thought the category would just be an additional field in the ratings model.  Could you expand more on how my original structure of a Review model and a rating model isn't DRY?  The Review model would just hold the Supervisor ID and date of review.

Answer (score 2):

If it will be trivial to add new fields later (not a lot of change control / paperwork, etc), I'd just go with the fields.

If you need to make it flexible for adding the new categories without changing the code, then you need to have 3 models:

```
Review 
  has_many :ratings

Category
  has_many :ratings

Rating
  belongs_to :review
  belongs_to :category
```

Store the name of the category in `Category` and the numeric value in `Rating`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to normalize, then another table for sure. I'd have a Review model and Category model (`Review has_many :categories`), but I'm not familiar with your problem domain. However, if people are reviewed on 8 categories next time, it's a no brainer to add one if you have a separate table.